# How does using time in linux works? Is it multithread related?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, time

I wrote a program in C++ using opencv. After some operations with feature extraction I show the results in an image

```
cv::imshow("ime", image);
cv::waitKey(1);
```

This operation is done multiple times (1000 times)

The program runs fine, no problem.

However if I want to time the program like

```
time theprogram.out
```

it runs for some time and then I got

```
Gdk-Error  The program 'ime' received an X Window System error
This probably reflects a bug in the program
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
(Details: serial 274 error code 10 request_code 130 (MIT-SHM minor code 1)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Investigating about this I found [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8407) with imshow and waitKey problems in multithread environments.

However my program is not multithread at all.

So I am wondering, does using time generates some kind of multithread environment?

Notes:

- The program without time works well
- If I replace `cv::waitKey(1)` with `cv:waitKey()` (and I have to click everytime) it works ok

Comment: Which `time` are you using, the Bash built-in or `/usr/bin/time`?

Comment: I think it is the bash one (not really sure)

Comment: The bash built-in forks a sub-shell followed by a call to getrusage. That shouldn't cause your issue. We might need to see a [mcve].